# Simplifying Composite Functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

***If the function is defined by $f(x+y) = kxy+f(x)+ 2y^2$ , where k is some constant for all real numbers and $g(x-g(y))=g(g(y))+xg(y)+g(x)-1$ for all $x,y$ belongs to real numbers then find range of $f(x) - g(\dfrac{1}{x})$ .....***

My Approach : First of all to find $f(x)$ I substituted $x=0$ and got $f(y) = f(0)+2y^2$ and as value of $f(0)=0$ so i got $f(y)=2y^2$ but i am not getting how to simplify $g(x)$....

Please help..

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Gerry Myerson , I am preparing for a competitive exam , so I got this question from a book of that exam.

Comment: How do you know that $f(0)=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
g(g(y))&=g(0-(-g(y)))\\&=g(-g(y))+g(0)-1.
\end{align}

Similarly, we have

\begin{align}
g(0-g(y))=g(g(y))+g(0)-1.
\end{align}

From these equations, we get $g(0)=1$. Next, put $y=0$ and use $g(0)=1$ to get

\begin{align}
g(x-1)=g(1)+x+g(x)-1.
\end{align}

Putting $x=1$, we get $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, we have

\begin{align}
g(x-1)&=x+g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\\&\Rightarrow g(x)-g(x-1)=\frac{1}{2}-x.
\end{align}

With this, we see that the form  of $g(x)$ should be that of a quadratic term, followed by any periodic function of period $1$. Assume $g(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c+p(x)$,  where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, and $p(x)$ is a periodic function of period $1$, i.e., $p(x-1)=p(x)$. Without loss of generality, assume $p(1)=0$ (if not, use $p(x)-p(1)$ in place of $p(x)$).

With $g(0)=1$, we see $c=1$. Also,

\begin{align}
ax^{2}+bx+1-\left(a(x-1)^{2}+b(x-1)+1\right)=\frac{1}{2}-x.
\end{align}

Equating the coefficients of $x^{2}$, $x$ and constant on both sides, we get $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=0$.

Thus, $g(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+1+p(x)=\frac{2-x^{2}}{2}+p(x)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "quadratic form only" statement is wrong, because you can add an arbitrary periodic function of period $1$ (solution of the homogeneous equation).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see something in your point. Can you please explain to me in detail?

Comment: I am getting a little confused of why you took the quadratic form .....and also have I calculated f(x) correctly .

Comment: $g(x)=\dfrac{2-x^2}2+43,725\sin(2\pi x)$is also a solution.

Comment: @saladi I think the value of $f(0)$ is not clear.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, you are right. Can you please tell me how to proceed from the point $g(x)-g(x-1)=\frac{1}{2}-x$?

Comment: @Karthik: hem, $g(x)=\dfrac{2-x^2}2+p(x)$ whith any periodic function.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I will edit the answer.